XSLT3 set json output to array of string without key
I am new to xslt,
I have a xml containing those elements
<cbl:ShippingAddress>
    <cbl:AddressLine AddressLineNumber="1">
        <cbl:Line>line1</cbl:Line>
    </cbl:AddressLine>
    <cbl:AddressLine AddressLineNumber="2">
        <cbl:Line>line2</cbl:Line>
    </cbl:AddressLine>
</cbl:ShippingAddress>

using this code
<map key="address">
    <array key="lines">
      <xsl:for-each select="/cbl:ShippingAddress/cbl:AddressLine/cbl:Line">
        <map>
          <string key="line">{.}</string>
        </map>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </array>
</map>

I get the output
"lines": [
    {
      "line": "line1"
    },
    {
      "line": "line2"
    }
],

I need my output to be like this, but can't figure out how
"lines": [
    "line1",
    "line2"
],

if i just change <array key="lines"> to <array>
I get the error message :
xml-to-json: Child elements of  must have a key attribute
is there a simple way to achieve this? i've browse many example, couldn't find it

nvm just had to remove the  attribute in between >.<

The required output you show is not a valid JSON.

Example
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:cbl="http://example.com/cbl"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <map>
        <array key="lines">
          <xsl:for-each select="cbl:ShippingAddress/cbl:AddressLine/cbl:Line/string()">
            <string>{.}</string>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </array>       
      </map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle example.

Here's another way you could look at this:
XML (corrected to well-formed!)
<cbl:ShippingAddress xmlns:cbl="http://example.com/cbl">
    <cbl:AddressLine AddressLineNumber="1">
        <cbl:Line>line1</cbl:Line>
    </cbl:AddressLine>
    <cbl:AddressLine AddressLineNumber="2">
        <cbl:Line>line2</cbl:Line>
    </cbl:AddressLine>
</cbl:ShippingAddress>

XSLT 3.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/cbl">
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/ShippingAddress">
    <xsl:sequence select="map{'lines':array{AddressLine/Line/text()}}" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
{ "lines": [
    "line1",
    "line2"
  ] }

Demo
